# oracle blob text right to left alignment

Tags: oracle, blob, rtf

I have an oracle table that contains blob field, and all data in that field is a text.

All text content are aligned to the left, I need oracle script or sql statement to align
all rows text to the right.

Comment: Why are you storing text in a `blob` rather than a `clob`? Anyway... what are you aligning against? Is this just for display (in which case where - what application or client etc.), or are you talking about updating all your data to be left-padded in the table? That would require every value, however short, to be padded to 4G, which is going to be a huge waste of space, so I really hope it's just a display issue. You at least need to determine how wide the displayed value should be, so you know what to align against.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I store text in blob because the control I use only working with blobs, I want to update all data but not to left pad I want to set text alignment to right. I am using Delphi with TRichView Control. can you help me?

Comment: Data in the table column has no alignment. I'm not familiar with Delphi so can't help you there, but i would guess that a control called that might have an alignment property.

Comment: The [features list for TRichView](http://www.trichview.com/features/text.html), if that is what you are using, says it supports left, right, center and justify alignment. This seems to be a display issue, not a database one.

Comment: Database is mostly like you have as RAW. Decorate it in client, and that is wise. Still..If you want to save it as Rich Text, you have to use HTML tags with the text. Ofcourse you have to parse it in client.

Comment: I used this kind of stuff with a .NET control by formatting in client side, send the formatted text(with html) to the database to save.

Comment: The final result I reached is text in blob stored with ltr alignment and the solution is to run delphi script that align all rows to the right one by one. by loading it in ritchEditView and align it to right and go to the next record..

Answer (score 0):

The final result I reached is text in blob stored with ltr alignment and the solution is to run delphi script that align all rows to the right one by one. by loading it in ritchEditView and align it to right and go to the next record..